# Check proof that if $\|f\|_{L^{\infty}{(\Omega)}}=0$ then $f=0 $ a.e on $\Omega$

Tags: measure-theory

Prove that for $p=\infty$ :

$\|f\|_{L^{\infty}{(\Omega)}}=0 \implies f=0 $ a.e on $\Omega$

Proof

$\|f\|_{L^{\infty}{(\Omega)}}=0 \implies \mathrm{ess}\sup |f| =0 \implies \inf\{a\in R| \mu\left(|f|^{-1}(a,\infty)\right)=0\}=0$

The above follows from the definition of essential supremum and the $L^{\infty}$ norm

Now clearly from the last expression we can deduce that
$a\geq0$

It follows from the definition  above that

$\forall a\geq 0 ,\mu\big(\{x||f(x)|>a\}\big)=0$
and as $\{x||f(x)| < 0\}=\phi $

and therefore $f=0$ a.e

I am not so convinced that this prof is correct. What do you say?

Comment: Your proof relies on the fact that $0$ is an element of $A:=\{a\geq 0 | \mu\left(|f|^{-1}(a,\infty)\right)=0\}$, but that isn't a consequence of $0=\inf A$. Instead, try to express $|f|^{-1}(0,\infty)$ as a countable union of sets which we *do* know to be null.